# Bottom bracket feels rough, should I replace it

Tags: repair, bottom-bracket

My bottom bracket feels rough when I turn it with my fingers. I don't notice any problems when it's all assembled, but it's definitely not smooth like the other parts of much bike like my pedal axles. It feels like there's sand or dirt in the bottom bracket. Do you think it's time to replace it? It's a cartridge bottom bracket (Truvativ PowerSpline) so I don't think it's serviceable.

Here's a video of what it sounds like. The picture quality shouldn't matter, but you should be able to hear the sound. You might need to jack up the sound or wear headphones to hear it best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like the bearing are dry. While you might get a few more miles out of it, I would replace it. As you stated it is a non serviceable bearing assembly. You have most of the work done already so why put it back together only to have to take it apart later.

Comment: It was pretty rough last spring when I took it apart, but just decided to put it back in. It's 4 years old now, and easily over 10,000 km so it's probably due for a change. Is there anything I can do to care for it better to make sure this doesn't happen again? I didn't really do much to the current one.

Comment: Even the best stuff wears out eventually. I would just buy a quality name brand replacement and follow the manufacturers instructions.

Comment: @Kibbee - One thing you can do, especially with cheap Shimano-style cartridges, is to coat the new cartridge in grease before installing, to help prevent rust.  While you're at it, also grease the inside of the BB housing.

Comment: "You can never have too much lube" ?